# Python Dataflow Template, making Runtime Parameters globally accessible

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

So the aim of the pipeline is to be able to use Runtime Variables to be able to open a csv file and name a BigQuery table.

All I need is to be able to access these variables globally, or within a ParDo, such as parsing it into the function.

I have tried creating a dummy string, then running a FlatMap to access the Runtime Parameters and make them global, although it returns nothing.

eg.

```
class CustomPipelineOptions(PipelineOptions):

    @classmethod
    def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
        parser.add_value_provider_argument(
            '--path',
            type=str,
            help='csv storage path')
        parser.add_value_provider_argument(
            '--table_name',
            type=str,
            help='Table Id')
def run()
    def rewrite_values(element):
        """ Rewrite default env values"""
        # global project_id
        # global campaign_id
        # global organization_id
        # global language
        # global file_path
        try:
            logging.info("File Path with str(): {}".format(str(custom_options.path)))
            logging.info("----------------------------")
            logging.info("element: {}".format(element))
            project_id = str(cloud_options.project)
            file_path = custom_options.path.get()
            table_name = custom_options.table_name.get()

            logging.info("project: {}".format(project_id))
            logging.info("File path: {}".format(file_path))
            logging.info("language: {}".format(table_name))
            logging.info("----------------------------")
        except Exception as e:
            logging.info("Error format----------------------------")
            raise KeyError(e)

        return file_path

    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions()
    cloud_options = pipeline_options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions)
    custom_options = pipeline_options.view_as(CustomPipelineOptions)
    pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True

    # Beginning of the pipeline
    p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)

    init_data = (p
                 | beam.Create(["Start"])
                 | beam.FlatMap(rewrite_values))

pipeline processing, running pipeline etc.
```

I can access the project variable no problem, although everything else returns as blank.

If I make the custom_options variable global, or when I pass a specific customs object into a function, such as: `| 'Read data' >> beam.ParDo(ReadGcsBlobs(path_file=custom_options.path))`, it only returns something such as `RuntimeValueProvider(option: path, type: str, default_value: None)`.

If I use `| 'Read data' >> beam.ParDo(ReadGcsBlobs(path_file=custom_options.path.get()))`, the variable is and empty string.

So in essence, I just need to access these variables globally, is it possible?

Finally to clarify, I do not want to use the `ReadFromText` method, I can use the runtime variable there, although to incorporate the runtime options into the dict created from the csv file will be to costly as I am working with huge csv files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me it worked by declaring `cloud_options` and `custom_options` as `global`:

```py
import argparse, logging

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import GoogleCloudOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import SetupOptions

class CustomPipelineOptions(PipelineOptions):

    @classmethod
    def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
        parser.add_value_provider_argument(
            '--path',
            type=str,
            help='csv storage path')
        parser.add_value_provider_argument(
            '--table_name',
            type=str,
            help='Table Id')

def rewrite_values(element):
        """ Rewrite default env values"""
        # global project_id
        # global campaign_id
        # global organization_id
        # global language
        # global file_path
        try:
            logging.info("File Path with str(): {}".format(str(custom_options.path.get())))
            logging.info("----------------------------")
            logging.info("element: {}".format(element))
            project_id = str(cloud_options.project)
            file_path = custom_options.path.get()
            table_name = custom_options.table_name.get()

            logging.info("project: {}".format(project_id))
            logging.info("File path: {}".format(file_path))
            logging.info("language: {}".format(table_name))
            logging.info("----------------------------")
        except Exception as e:
            logging.info("Error format----------------------------")
            raise KeyError(e)

        return file_path


def run(argv=None):
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)

  global cloud_options
  global custom_options

  pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
  cloud_options = pipeline_options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions)
  custom_options = pipeline_options.view_as(CustomPipelineOptions)
  pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True

  # Beginning of the pipeline
  p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)

  init_data = (p
               | beam.Create(["Start"])
               | beam.FlatMap(rewrite_values))

  result = p.run()
  # result.wait_until_finish

if __name__ == '__main__':
  run()
```

After setting the `PROJECT` and `BUCKET` variables I staged the template with:

```sh
python script.py \
    --runner DataflowRunner \
    --project $PROJECT \
    --staging_location gs://$BUCKET/staging \
    --temp_location gs://$BUCKET/temp \
    --template_location gs://$BUCKET/templates/global_options
```

And execute it with providing `path` and `table_name` options:

```sh
gcloud dataflow jobs run global_options \
   --gcs-location gs://$BUCKET/templates/global_options \
   --parameters path=test_path,table_name=test_table
```

And the runtime parameters seem to be logged fine inside the FlatMap:

[image]

Comment: Ok, thanks Guillem, but as I said in the question I want it to be extracted in a templated version. With making "Runtime Parameters" global.

Comment: I included my pipeline options class in the answer.

Comment: Yes, you're right @jmoore255. My idea was to show how to make them globally available, and it was quicker to test with executing the job directly. Now I have edited my answer to run it from a template (it works too) so it's more in accordance with the question.

Comment: Thanks @Guillem Xercavins, I was actually using a similar method before but it wasn't working, I haven't really worked out why it was failing. But starting again and doing it the same way you did it worked, also it's possible to pass it through in a ParDo, as in this example [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/creating-templates#using-valueprovider-in-your-functions).